# Programmatically Control C# Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a [USB spectrum analyzer](http://www.rfinstruments.com/SA0314.html) that I would like to control programmatically. Luckily, the website comes with a [sample Visual Studio solution](http://www.rfinstruments.com/php/pdf/sourcecodeSA0314.zip) that hooks into their driver. I was able to compile and run the sample code they provided, but the sample code seems to generate a custom GUI display that still requires the user to click buttons and such.

I want a CLI that I can run and everything will be done automatically. However, it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to do this. I peeked into the DLL metadata, and this is what is exposed to me:

```
namespace SA0314Ctrl
{
    public class SA0314Ctrl : Component
    {
        public List<PointF> swpData;

        public SA0314Ctrl();
        public SA0314Ctrl(IContainer container);

        public event EventHandler OnDeviceRemoved;
        public event EventHandler OnDeviceReady;
        public event EventHandler OnDataAvailable;
        public event EventHandler OnSweepComplete;

        public byte GetBw();
        public string GetDeviceSn();
        public void ParseMessages(ref Message m);
        public void RegisterHandle(IntPtr Handle);
        public void SetBw(byte val);
        public void SetIfGain(byte val);
        public void StartSweep(double startFreq, double stepFreq, ushort numPts);
        public void StopSweep();
        public void SweepSingle(double startFreq, double stepFreq, ushort numPts);
        public bool UnregisterHandle();
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing);
    }
}
```

I tried using the parameterless constructor, but then the events never fire (if I assign handlers) and none of the actual APIs work (they all return NullPointerException). It seems like I have to use a Form so I can pass an `IContainer` to the constructor and a `IntPtr` to `RegisterHandle`. But I don't want a GUI that someone has to click! The whole point of this is to automate the collection of frequency domain measurements with `StartSweep` and `StopSweep`.

Is it possible to create a Form, but then hook into it programmatically instead of waiting for user input?

Comment: You almost surely need Application.Run() to get those events fired.  An example of another component that needs it [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034).

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I also had to call `RegisterHandle(new IntPtr())` for some reason, but after doing that everything is working in CLI the same as it works in the GUI!